# Celery app ignoring beat_schedule option specified in settings.py file

Tags: django, celery

I am trying to extend my django app with celery crontab functionality. For this purposes i created **celery.py** file where i put code as mentioned in official documentation.

Here is my the code from **project/project/celery.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','project.settings')
app=Celery('project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf::settings',namespace='CELERY')
```

Than inside my **project/settings.py** file i specify related to celery configs as follow

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Europe/Moscow"
CELERYBEAT_SHEDULE = {
    'test_beat_tasks':{
        'task':'webhooks.tasks.adding',
        'schedule':crontab(minute='*/1),
     },
}
```

Than i run worker an celery beat in the same terminal by
`celery -A project worker -B`

But nothing happened i mean i didnt see that my celery beat task printing any output while i expected that my task **webhooks.tasks.adding** will execute

Than i decided to check that celery configs are applied. For this purposes in command line **python manage.py shell i checked celery.app.conf object

```
#i imported app from project.celery.py module 
from project import celery

#than examined app configs
celery.app.conf
```

And inside of huge config's output of celery configs i saw that **timezone is set to None**

As i understand my problem is that initiated in **project/celery.py** app is ignoring my project/settings.py CELERY_TIMEZONE and CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE configs but why so? What i am doing wrong? Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

After i spent so much time researching to solve this problem i found that my mistake was inside how i run worker and celery beat. While running worker as i did it wouldnt execute task in the terminal. To see is task is executing i should run it as follow `celery -A project worker -B -l INFO` or instead of INFO if you want more detailed output DEBUG can be added. Hope it will help anyone